# Count (*) multiplied with some values in PL SQL developer

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a problem when I use count (*) multiplied with some value in case statement.

**This is my code -**

```
  SELECT DISTINCT
         plmn,
         CASE
            WHEN timestamp < '20130300' THEN (COUNT (*) * 0.02)
            ELSE (COUNT (*) * 0.03)
         END
            AS total
    FROM tap_out
   WHERE teleservicecode = '22' AND calltype = 'MOC'
-- AND timestamp LIKE '201303%'
GROUP BY plmn, timestamp
```

**And I receive these values -**

[image]

**However, this is wrong, because when I use count(*) multiplied with some value not in case statement I receive other values. This is the code -**

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       plmn, count (*)  * 0.02 AS total
            FROM tap_out
           WHERE     teleservicecode = '22'
                 AND calltype = 'MOC'
                -- AND timestamp LIKE '201303%'
        GROUP BY plmn
```

**And I receive these values -**

[image]

**How I can correct the count in the fisrt select statement, so that I can receive the correct values?**

Comment: You're grouping and filtering differently; why do you expect the same results? In the first example you're grouping by timestamp so you'll almost always only have one matching record at a time (depending on the precision and your data), so every record will get `1 * 0.02`; and your `distinct` reduces that to a single row in the result set for each `plmn`.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't have to do with the case. In the second query you don't group by timestamp, so it is very likely that you have higher counts and less total records. The first query would return much, much more records, but you're filtering them all by using `distinct`.

Try this:

```
SELECT
  plmn,
  COUNT(*) * Multiplyer AS total
FROM  
  (SELECT
    plmn,
    CASE WHEN timestamp < '20130300' THEN 
      0.02
    ELSE
      0.03
    END AS Multiplyer
  FROM
    tap_out
  WHERE 
    teleservicecode = '22' AND calltype = 'MOC')
GROUP BY
  plmn,
  Multiplyer
```

Comment: I think you are missing the case when a plmn has timestamp greater and smaller than 20130300, but I'm tired, so I can be wrong :)

Comment: @mucio How can a timestamp be both greater and smaller than a single value?

Comment: I wrote that I was tired, I missed that you were using Multiplyer to group by

Answer (score 1):

try to write the query like this:

```
-- then I sum the value for plmn
SELECT plmn,
       sum(val) total
FROM (
    -- first I calculate the value for each plmn/timestamp couple
    SELECT   plmn,
             CASE
                WHEN timestamp < '20130300' THEN (COUNT (*) * 0.02)
                ELSE (COUNT (*) * 0.03)
             END
                AS val
        FROM tap_out
       WHERE teleservicecode = '22' AND calltype = 'MOC'
    -- AND timestamp LIKE '201303%'
    GROUP BY plmn, timestamp
)
GROUP BY plmn
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need?

```
SELECT plmn,
       Sum(CASE
            WHEN timestamp < '20130300'
            THEN 0.02
            ELSE 0.03
         END)
            AS total
FROM   tap_out
WHERE  teleservicecode = '22' AND
       calltype = 'MOC'
GROUP BY plmn
```